# Custom Permalinks issue with YOAST - Showing category.php before page-template.php

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permalinks, yoast

I have a problem with YOAST on my site. When it´s deactivated everything is fine, but if I activate YOAST the permalink to my template-pages stop working. Instead of going to the page-template.php file, they go straight to category.php instead.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: After activating, try saving your premalinks in the settings. If that doesn't help check every setting in Yoast, is there a setting that uses the same slug as that page?

Comment: Iv´e tryied that. It work's if I choose any other permalink structure, it´s only a problem with custom permalink. The pages that dont work aren't a cpt, they only list cpt:s and work with a page-template.php file. The odd thing is that one page works, then it´s 6 or 7 who dont work...